# Remove times from a loop in php

Tags: php

I have a database, which contains the start time and end time for service, and a start time and end time for rest, for example:
Opening hours are from 08:00 to 19:00, however we do not work between 12:00 and 13:00, the opening hours have intervals, for example: every 15 minutes, how do I remove the opening hours? rest of my system? PHP and mysql, an excerpt of the code:

```
$inicio = $val1P;
$fim = $val2P;

// Quebra horas de minutos
$t1 = explode(':', $inicio);
$t2 = explode(':', $fim);

// Converte para minutos
$min_i = ($t1[0] * 60 + $t1[1]);
$min_f = ($t2[0] * 60 + $t2[1]);
// Define o formato
$formato = '%02d:%02d';
//Loop para impressão
$disable='';
for ($i = $min_i; $i < $min_f; $i += $intervalo) {

    // Transforma de minutos para horas
    $horas = floor($i / 60);
    // Divide os minutos e tras o resto
    $minutos = ($i % 60);

    $horario = sprintf($formato, $horas, $minutos);

    // Imprime
    echo '<tr><td><div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxPrimary' . $i . '" '.$disable.'>
        <label for="checkboxPrimary' . $i . '">
        ' . $horario . '
        </label>
        </div> </td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Do you think you want to use [continue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) ?

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are an array of strings, not int. The math expression will still work but bear that in mind. ... What is `$intervalo`?

Comment: Could you send an example following the logic of what I need?

Comment: $range = 15; interval is a period of time of service that will be carried out

Comment: I can't understand what you said

Comment: Where did $range come from? Are you translating your variable names now? Dont do that, stick to the source. Otherwise your comments will refer to things that dont exist.

Comment: Sorry, I'm Brazilian, and some variables in my code are Portuguese, so I have to translate, but the idea is that the times between 12:00 and 13:00 are removed or disabled

Comment: "so I have to translate" ... For who? If the variables are spelled a certain way in your code, spell it the same way here in comments.

Comment: It would be nice however if you translated your comments (in your code) to english. By translating your comments (in your code) to english you help others help you all the more faster, if at all.

Comment: I practically need a function in PHP, to leave only the opening hours, I have the total daily hours, which are from 08:00 to 19:00 and within these times I have the intervals from 12:00 to 13:00, I I only need to have the time of 13:00, which is the time that starts working, taking into account that it is listing all times every 15 minutes, example: 12:00, 12:15, 12:30, 12:45 , 13:00, I want these to be removed and only 12:00 blocked and 13:00 available to start scheduling

Comment: Where is the [mcve]?

Comment: Here's an example using [DatePeriod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) instead of your manual time arithmetic - https://3v4l.org/Ip9pF